# Counting instances of values across columns and rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of instances a particular value is present within a table. For example:

```
   userID1  userID2  userID3
    40       36        0
    36       0         0
    36       40        0
```

I want to be able to say that there are 2-40s, 3-36s and 4-0s.
I was able to do it for each column individually the problem I run into is when the IDs are offset from each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't really said what the results are to be like but an easy way is to use UNION to bring the 3 columns into 1, then count normally:

```
SELECT
  x.userid, count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT userid1 as userID FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid2 FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid3 FROM table
) x
GROUP BY x.userid
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you for that!